# Structure pointer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int c;
int main()
{
        struct abc{
        int *a;
        char *ch[10];
        };
        struct abc obj1;
        struct abc *obj;
        obj = & obj1;
        scanf("%d",obj->a);
        printf("\nY");
        scanf("%s",&obj->ch);
        printf("\nY");
return 0;
}
```

I am using VIM editor and Gcc compiler on fedora..
i get an SEGMENTATION FAULT (CORE DUMPED??) //What does it mean??

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Answer (score 5):

"Segementation fault" means that your program tried to access memory that it wasn't allowed to.  Your program has several pointer and initialization errors.

I think you want your array to be `char ch[10]`, not `char *ch[10]`.  You also need to change the `scanf()` call to match:  `scanf("%s", obj->ch);`.

The same goes for your `a` field.  It should probably not be a pointer, and you should pass a pointer to `scanf()`:

```
scanf("%d", &obj->a);
```

Comment: I believe the `a` field is fine as is. `scanf` will expect the address to an integer in that instance, and because `a` itself is a pointer (address) to an integer, it will work fine. However, unless you have reason to, it's probably best to make a just an `int` and then pass the address of it as you mentioned.

Comment: @Shynthriir - it is most definitely *not* fine the way it is.  `a` is a pointer, but it doesn't point to anything!

Comment: Okay, sorry, he would have to allocate memory for it first. The point I was trying to make was that passing an (allocated) pointer to an int or passing the address to an int shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

> i get an SEGMENTATION FAULT (CORE DUMPED??) //What does it mean??

A variable doing a memory access violation results segmentation fault.

```
scanf("%d",obj->a);
```

`int *a;` - struct member `a` is an uninitialized pointer but trying to take input on to the location it is pointing to. Causing you segmentation fault.

```
 obj->a = malloc(sizeof(int)) ;
```

Now you can take input for `a` pointing location.

```
 scanf("%d", &(obj->a) );
```

---

With the kind of input operations you perform, the struct definition need not need raw pointers -

```
struct abc{
    int *a;         // Change this to int a; or make a point to a valid memory location
    char *ch[10];   // Change this to char ch[10]; or initialize it with pointers pointing to a valid memory locations
                    // and then take input on to pointer pointing location.
};
```

Note the difference between the two -

```
int a  ;  // Can take input directly to "a"
int *a ;  // First "a" must point to a valid memory location that can hold an int
          // Then, can take input to "a" pointing location
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `scanf("%d", obj -> a)` ? `a` is a pointer so it itself contains an address.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Carl's answer: `char *ch[10]` creates an array of 10 pointers to a character. What you want is an array to 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour.

You should have `char ch[10];` and use scanf with a preset width to avoid overflows

```
scanf("9%s",&obj->ch);
```

More : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

The struct is defined to have a pointer-to-int, which you never initialize, hence pointing to random location, hence writing to a memory place you do not own, hence `UB`. Either switch that to a local variable `int a` or `malloc()` an integer.